# I want to move button up when android keyboard appears and down when keyboard disappear

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to move button up when android keyboard appears and down when keyboard disappear 
 currently keyboard is coming over button .
See screenshot
[image: screeshot]
I have already tried as below but not coming above of keyboard .

```
<android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/slide_name_title"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"

            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:textColor="#283D65"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/slide_1_1_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:textColor="#8E8E8E"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_title1"
             />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/slide_1_desc"
            android:textColor="#2A3042"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc" />




        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Full Name (Eg. John Smith)"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#8E8E8E"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/editTextUserName" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_above="@+id/password"
            android:background="#E0E0E0"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"></View>


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        >
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:text="नमस्ते"
            android:backgroundTint="#2DC9D7"

            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"

            android:background="@drawable/button_corner"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:id="@+id/btn_name_next"/>
        <Button
        android:text="Hello"
        android:backgroundTint="#2DC9D7"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_corner"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:id="@+id/btn_name_next1"/>
        <Button
        android:text="Hi"
        android:backgroundTint="#2DC9D7"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

        android:background="@drawable/button_corner"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:id="@+id/btn_name_next2"/>
    </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why you add button inside ViewFlipper?

Comment: put your relative layout in `ScrollView` and keep the `ScrollView` as parent view

Comment: @Magesh Pandian View flipper using for animation in button's text.

Comment: Inside your `Manifest` file, add this inside your activity, where your keyword is open: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score 4):

**Use this code it will solve your problem and comment me if any problem.**

> Use below line in your activity in android manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

> Working for below layout code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textColor="#283D65"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="Happy To see you! Let's get to know each other"
        android:textColor="#8E8E8E"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="What should we call you?"
        android:textColor="#2A3042"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:hint="Full Name (Eg. John Smith)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#8E8E8E" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"></View>


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_name_next"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#000"
            android:backgroundTint="#2DC9D7"
            android:text="नमस्ते"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_name_next1"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#000"
            android:backgroundTint="#2DC9D7"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_name_next2"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#000"
            android:backgroundTint="#2DC9D7"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the button in a frame layout and set fitSystemWindows property of framelayout to true

Comment: try use scrollview. Since you have set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" its already trying to put all above keyboard but relative layout not good for that. put your root relative layout in a scrolview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

wrap your top layout in scrollview: leaving the buttons layout

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now in Buttons layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

For some reason this works for me..

**EDIT**

call this: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Comment: the scrollview should be under your top tag `Relativelayout`..and apply ` `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the bottom layout containing the button..

Comment: yes same did but not coming up button while keyboard is appearing

Comment: Button goes up above of Edittext faraway from keyboard

Comment: use your previous layout...and chcek if you use any margin bottom ...attribute

Comment: used previous layout and not using margin bottom still same problem button is going above with EditText .

Comment: maybe it's because of Viewflipper..check the margin ..it's difficult to debug for me..